# Sublime Text: Hide Sidebar if not project

Tags: configuration, sublimetext3, configuration-files, behavior

So, I managed to configure ST3 to keep the sidebar open, because most of the time I'm working with projects and it's handy.

However, when I'm not working with projects it's a pain to have to deal with the sidebar, because:

1. Sublime always opens different single files on new windows: Is there
   a way to control this and make it open on the same window, so they
   all show on the sidebar?
2. Is there a way to specifically tell it to only show the sidebar on projects and display tabs with all the open files on the top?

Thank you!